# All the section titles showing in one section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a grouped tableview and for some reason all the section titles display only in one section. So the result is that the titles are all on top of each other in section = 0. All of the other sections are blank.

I tried debugging and see that when section == 1, the headerLabel is nil.

I am using a custom view as the header, here is that code:

```
class HeaderView: UIView {

let headerLabel =  UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addCustomView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addCustomView() {
    self.addSubview(headerLabel)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(headerLabelConstraints())
}

private func headerLabelConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    let leadingAnchor = headerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor)
    let trailingAnchor = headerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor)
    let topAnchor = headerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor)
    let heightAnchor = headerLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
    headerLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return [leadingAnchor, trailingAnchor, topAnchor, heightAnchor]
}
```

}

Here is how I am calling it in the tableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! HeaderView
}

//for reference: sectionHeaderHeight = 44
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight
}

//for reference: sectionTitles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"]
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = HeaderView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    headerView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    headerView.headerLabel.text = sectionTitles[section]
    headerView.headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    return headerView
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

I noticed a couple of other issues. Here's how to resolve them:

#### In your `HeaderView` implementation:

1. Remove `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` from the `init(frame:)` method.

*(A `UITableView` always needs fixed row heights for both cells and header / footer views. If you're using Auto Layout to determine the row's height the system first computes the necessary height, then sets the corresponding bounds for the respective view and then adds a fixed width and a fixed height constraint that "simulate" these bounds. If you deactivate `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the view you also deactivate that last step and the view never gets its correct height set.)*

2. Add a bottom constraint:

   ```
   let bottomAnchor = headerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
   // ...
   return [leadingAnchor, trailingAnchor, topAnchor, bottomAnchor, heightAnchor]
   ```

*(If you only connect the top, left and right layout anchors of the label with those of its superview the superview's height is not bound to the label's height. Its height will actually be 0. This is why all your labels are stacked on top of each other.)*

#### In your view controller implementation that contains a reference to the table view:

3. Add the following lines to its `viewDidLoad()` method:

   ```
   tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 44
   ```

*(This is how you tell the table view that you do not want to use a fixed header view height but you want the table view to automatically compute the height by resolving the Auto Layout constraints you added to the view. The estimated height doesn't need to be exactly 44. It should only be close to the average value of your header view heights.)*

---

### Original Answer:

Seems like you haven't "told" your table view how many sections it should have. Simply implement

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sectionTitles.count
}
```

in your table view's data source. (If omitted the number of sections defaults to 1.)

---

By the way:
Your implementation

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! HeaderView
}
```

doesn't really make sense. It simply creates a constant and doesn't do anything with the constant. The compiler should actually show a yellow warning for this line. So unless you need to do something right before a header view is displayed just remove the whole method.

Comment: Hi @Mischa, thanks for the suggestions. The numberOfSections is implemented but the problem persists.

Comment: You're right. There were other issues. Update my answer.